# How do I create a scope to find all objects in my class that `include?` a string on an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Node` object that has an attribute called `cached_user_tag_list`, that stores a comma separated list of email addresses as a string like this:

```
[3] pry(main)> n.cached_user_tag_list
=> "gerry@test.com, danny@test.com"
```

If I set a local variable to be one of those email addresses, I can use ruby's `include?` string method to find if a `node` contains that email address. Here is an illustration:

```
[6] pry(main)> g = "gerry@test.com"
=> "gerry@test.com"
[8] pry(main)> n.cached_user_tag_list.include? g
=> true
```

What I would like to do, is create a Scope on my `Node` class/model that will accept `g` and search against the column/attribute `cached_user_tag_list` for all the `Nodes` in my DB and return a collection or AR Relation of all of those Nodes that contain that email address stored in the variable `g` within their string at `cached_user_tag_list`.

How do I do this?

**Edit 1**

I tried `Node.where('cached_user_tag_list.include?'(g))`, but that didn't work.

Comment: is cached_user_tag_list a column ?  or some or serialized or unserialized attribute derived from a column ?

Comment: @RishavRastogi It is a column...yes. The datatype for the column is `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just plain old string column with comma separated values, you can do something like this:

`scope :find_nodes_which_include, ->(email) { |email| where("cache_user_tag_list like ?", "%#{email}%")  }`

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I was looking for. I knew I could do something like this, just couldn't nail down the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: mind that this can be sloooow: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning